# Custom SliverAppBar flexible space shape using a CustomClipper

Tags: flutter

So in flutter, I want to make a `SliverAppBar`, but I want it to have a custom shape like: [image: in this picture it has a depression].

I have the shape (or Cliper if you will) defined:

```
class DepressionAppBarClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  final double radius;
  
  DepressionAppBarClipper(this.radius);
  
  @override
  
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();

    path.lineTo(0, size.height);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      0, size.height - radius, 
      radius, size.height - radius
    );

    path.lineTo(size.width - radius, size.height - radius);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      size. width, size.height - radius,
      size.width, size.height
    );

    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);

    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => false;
}
```

And have managed to achieve a sliver that acts like a `SliverAppBar` using a `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              delegate: MyCustomHeaderDelegate(),
              pinned: true,
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text('Item $index'),
                  );
                },
                childCount: 50,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: DepressionAppBarClipper(60.0), // Your custom shape clipper
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            'Custom Shape AppBar',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 200.0;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 100.0;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

But there aren't any predefined properties that `SliverAppBar` does, and I want exactly that - **for it to act like a `SliverAppBar`, but just have this custom shape dictated by my defined cliper stated above.**

**EDIT: SOLUTION:** Create a class that extends `ShapeBorder`. In my case, it is:

```
class AppBarShapeBorder extends ShapeBorder {
  final double radius;

  const AppBarShapeBorder(this.radius);

  @override
  EdgeInsetsGeometry get dimensions => EdgeInsets.zero;

  @override
  Path getInnerPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Path(); // Define inner path if needed
  }

  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    // Define your custom shape path here
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(rect.left, rect.top);
    path.lineTo(rect.left, rect.bottom);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      rect.left,          rect.bottom - radius, 
      rect.left + radius, rect.bottom - radius
    );

    path.lineTo(rect.right - radius, rect.bottom - radius);

    path.quadraticBezierTo(
      rect.right, rect.bottom - radius,
      rect.right, rect.bottom
    );

    path.lineTo(rect.right, rect.top);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Rect rect, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    // Define your painting logic here
    Paint paint = Paint()..color = Colors.transparent;
    canvas.drawPath(getOuterPath(rect), paint);
  }

  @override
  ShapeBorder scale(double t) {
    // Implement scaling if needed
    return this;
  }
}
```

And then asign this class instance to `SliverAppBar.shape` like so:

```
SliverAppBar(
  shape: AppBarShapeBorder(20.0),
),
```

Comment: try this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/shape.html - the docs say: "The shape of the app bar's Material as well as its shadow"

Comment: Thanks! I managed to get this working with the shape parameter